# flutter drop-down list - retrieve selected value and not in a box format

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have made a drop-down list as in the following screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ6Qc.png)

Here:

1. I want the drop-down to be in a box like other TextFormFields and arrow to be bigger
2. my drop-down list background seems to be blurred and not visible
3. I want the selected value to be replaced on "Choose the id proof"
   Following is my code:

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
  color: Colors.white,
  child: _hintDown(),
),
SizedBox(height: 10),
```

my dropdown code is:

```dart
DropdownButton _hintDown() => DropdownButton<String>(
  items: [
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: "1",
      child: Text(
        "Aadhar Card",
      ),
    ),
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: "2",
      child: Text(
        "Pancard",
      ),
    ),
  ],
  onChanged: (value) {
    print("value: $value");
  },
  hint: Text(
    "Choose the id proof!",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is this code enough or do I need to go for some other?

Comment: in order to be able to help you we need more information, in the dartpad provided code looks completely different from images linked in a description (can of course have something to do with the fact, that web version is still in its beta, but still)

Comment: Checkout the answer, and let me know if that is what you were searching for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain changes in the code as per the requirements. You must visit the flutter documentation and read about using [DropdownButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) to achieve what you want

See the code clearly, and implement the code in your code base

```
  // look at the comments too to understand the functionality
  String dropdownValue = 'Choose the id proof!';
  
  // Return a widgt container to give the border
  // and then wrap it around your DropdownButton
  Widget _hintDown() => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
        iconSize: 30, //this inicrease the size
        elevation: 16,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        // this is for underline
        // to give an underline us this in your underline inspite of Container
  //       Container(
  //         height: 2,
  //         color: Colors.grey,
  //       )
        underline: Container(), 
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue;
          });
        },
        items: <String>['Choose the id proof!', 'Adhaar Card', 'Pancard', 'Voter card', 'Passport']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
    )
  );
```

**Result**

[image: Result GIF]